# what is difference between classnames vs classNames from classnames package

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, classname

I see some project using classnames or classNames to apply multiple class into element. I am wondering what is difference between them and which I should use if I am under my typescript react project? From my example code, I can't see the difference

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-dubinsky-gn689)

```
// App.tsx
import "./styles.css";
import classnames from "classnames";
import classNames from "classnames";

export default function App() {
  const h1ClassName = classnames("h_classnames", { label__h1: true });
  const h2ClassName = classNames("h_classNames", { label__h2: true });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className={h1ClassName}>I use classnames</h1>
      <h1 className={h2ClassName}>I use classNames</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

// style.css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.h_classnames {
  color: blue;
}

.h_classNames {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: `import iCanNameItWhateverIWant from "classnames";`

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference, it's the same function. The default export of `classnames` is the function, you're just providing an alias for it and importing it twice.

For example:

```
import "./styles.css";
import foo from "classnames";
import bar from "classnames";

export default function App() {
  const h1ClassName = foo("h_classnames", { label__h1: true });
  const h2ClassName = bar("h_classNames", { label__h2: true });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className={h1ClassName}>I use classnames</h1>
      <h1 className={h2ClassName}>I use classNames</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```